# Gramaticalmente, ¿qué es "yo que tú jugaba"?

Tags: gramática

Estaba escuchando hoy la radio cuando oí un anuncio sobre un sorteo de lotería. Al final de este, alguien decía:

> Yo que tú jugaba

La frase la entiendo: "si yo fuera tú, jugaría [o participaría en este premio de lotería]". Sin embargo, me surgió la idea de qué es gramaticalmente este "yo que tú"

Mirando en la RAE me parece que encaja con este caso:

> [**que**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UkbUarn)
>
> 4. conj. Introduce una oración subordinada sustantiva. *Quiero que estudies. El miedo a que salga mal. Es imposible que lo olvide.*

Sin embargo, me pregunto si tal estructura tiene algún tipo de denominación.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que se considera una [construcción condicional](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=bnooacxygzYFLlNw)

La expresión `yo que tú` tiene valor condicional, equivale a:

`Si yo fuera tú...`
`En tu lugar, yo...`

y se puede construir con el verbo en condicional o en imperfecto.